# Offline, cross-platform calendar client

Tags: linux, osx, offline, calendar, synchronization

I'm trying to find a calendar client to replace Apple Calendar, which has a poor UI and many bugs.

Requirements:

- Must run on at least macOS and Arch Linux *(rules out Apple Calendar)*
- Must display graphical week view *(rules out emacs-calfw)*
- Must display always-visible notifications *(rules out Thunderbird + Lightning)*
- Must work offline *(rules out Google Calendar)*
- Must be able to sync with either Google Calendar or Apple Calendar
- Preferably free/open-source, but only requirement is it's not a subscription service

I'm willing to do some legwork here, to the point of possibly implementing a graphical week view in emacs-calfw myself if there really are no better options.

Comment: I am (still) looking for a software exactly matching your requierments.
So I was wondering, if you actually did write your own software and if this would be an open source project.
- Achim

Comment: It's _very_ deep on my backlog. Some unfinished Elisp in https://github.com/raxod502/ishikk, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at Rainlander, I checked your list:

- macOS and Linux? Yes.
- Week view? Yes.
- Always-visible notifications? Yes.
- Works offline? Yes.
- Syncs with Google Calendar? Yes.
- Free? There is a "lite" version. But for "pro" is a one-time purchase.

I hope this is what you were looking for. Cheers.

Link: http://www.rainlendar.net/

In addition to the above, you can also look into some platform specific options, like **Fantastical** and **BusyCal** for macOS, or **Kontact** for Linux.

Links: 

https://flexibits.com/fantastical

https://userbase.kde.org/Kontact

https://www.busymac.com/

Comment: In Rainlendar, is there a way to reschedule an event by dragging it? So far I cannot figure out how to do it, nor does it seem to be documented in [the user guide](http://www.rainlendar.net/download/UserGuide-English.pdf).

Comment: I am not really sure. It has been a long time since I used it. But I think it would be best for you to try it (use the lite version). See if you like it. Sometimes the lack of some features are compensated by others. It is really flexible.

Comment: I looked at it for a while, but the interface just seems extremely clunky and ill-designed for macOS at least. All the text for times of day is clipped off the side of the window, for example.

Comment: Yes not very eye-candy. Some skins/themes do make up for it but in all seems dated. Have you tried Fantastical, or BusyCal for Mac? I don't understand why you need to have the exact same software for both environments (being a calendar app). I don't really use Linux much but looking into the Calendar that comes with Ubuntu it looks great.

Comment: Another tool that is also great would be GeekTool. It has a lot of implementations (look at battery consumption, hard drive space, etc) and also have calendar options. On GeekTool however you will not be able to drag-and-drop events on the calendar. The good side is that it is 100% customizable, so you can make it look like anything you want.

Comment: I looked at Fantastical and BusyCal, and they both look like good software which solves my problem. In the end, I think I will actually end up writing my own software, because I'm cheap. However, these are all good answers to the question I asked, and as such I'm accepting this answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks Radon I will update the answer to be more complete. I was still looking into some additional calendars for Linux, and maybe "Kontact" can be a better option than the pre-installed version? Cheers.